# Not able to embed a SVG file using xlink:href

Tags: html, svg

I need to embed a SVG file in a HTML document. File Example.svg is in the same directory of the HTMl file.

Using the following code, no SVG is inserted and nothing shown, but looking at network debut panel in Chrome DEV tools  i can see the SVG is loaded.

What could be wrong and how to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="250" height="250">
            <use xlink:href="Example.svg"></use>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Content of my SVG file https://jsfiddle.net/900xLbor/

Same problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/900xLbor/2/

Comment: Related: http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-SVG11-20100622/struct.html#UseElement

Comment: Also potentially related https://css-tricks.com/ajaxing-svg-sprite/

Comment: In your second jsFiddle, you have linked to a png rendering of the example svg.Link to the actual svg file, set a reasonable viewport on your svg tag, and try again. Also there might be cross-domain issues with what you're trying to do, so check your console. See here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=470601

Comment: @alexg thanks for your comment. I have edited my jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/900xLbor/2/ I have this problem on the same domain as well. Please let me know your toughs thanks.

Comment: I have no error in Chrome console.

Comment: You need to set the id of the element to use into the href (`xlink:href="example.svg#svg2"`, but it only works locally for me) [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/eR5QdRjaCWO2iRgC4jdJ?p=preview)

Comment: @Kaiido great, thanks for your comment, please add it as an nswer I would be glad to accept it thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MDN article about xlink:href attribute on the `<use>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href) :

> An `<IRI>` reference to an element/fragment within an SVG document.

In other words, you need to set the id of the element to use into the href :
`<use xlink:href="Example.svg#svg2"/>`

[Here is a plunker demonstration](http://plnkr.co/edit/eR5QdRjaCWO2iRgC4jdJ?p=preview)